# Why is createUserWithEmailAndPassword not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email=((EditText)findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
            String password=((EditText)findViewById(R.id.password)).getText().toString();
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener( new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this,"Hooray!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this,"Ohhno!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

[This is my layout file snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u37ik.png)

I have also enabled email password authentication in firebase.

Comment: in `else` check out `task.getException()` and you will find out why task wasn't sucessful

Comment: Is any of the Toast messages displayed?

Comment: No, I realized my mistake that I was trying to log in with the same google account which also I am using for Firebase login, so it showed an error. Else, it's working fine if we log in with other mail ids